# Bounds on Eigen Values of a Covariance Matrix of Bounded Random Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, covariance

Suppose we have a random vector ${\bf X} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where every element of ${\bf X}$ has a per element bound $ |X_i| \le a_i$.

Now let ${\bf K}_{\bf X}$ be the covariance matrix of ${\bf X}$.

**My question:** Can we give bounds on the individual eigenvalues of ${\bf K}_{\bf X}$. Recall, that ${\bf K}_{\bf X}$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite.

I was able to give a bound on the sum of eigenvalues (here we use the fact that sum of eigen values equal to the trace of ${\bf K}_{\bf X}$)
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = Tr({\bf K}_{\bf X}) = \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2] \le  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2.
\end{align}

However, I am not sure how to do it or if it can be done for the individual eigenvalue.

Comment: If the sum of the eigenvalues is bounded, and each eigenvalue is no-less than 0, then every eigenvalue is bound by the sum.

Comment: @Guangliang Thanks. But this is not very tight. Right?

Comment: @Body I don't know how much else you can do without knowing more about the joint distribution.

Comment: @Guangliang  I was thinking that we can also bound the cross terms $E[X_iX_j] \le a_i a_j$. So, we can have a bound on every term of the matrix.  Doesn't this mean that $K_X \preceq A$ where $A_{ij}=a_{i}a_j$. And now perhaps there is some inequality for eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Consider the case of $n=2$, the diagonals are $a_1^2$ and $a_2^2$.  Depending on the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$, the eigenvalues can vary from $\{a_1^2,a_2^2\}$ in the case of 0 correlation, to $\{0, a_1^2+a_2^2\}$ for the case of correlation equals to $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Gershgorin Circle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).
In general is says that all eigen values lies between the discs which are a function of the diagonal and a row sum (Column as well for Symmetric Matrices).

We define the $ {r}_{i} $ disc radius as:

$$ {r}_{i} = \sum_{j \neq i} {m}_{ij} $$

The [disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics)) $ {D}_{i} \left( {m}_{ii}, {r}_{i} \right) = \left\{ x \mid \left| x - {m}_{ii} \right| \leq {r}_{i} \right\} $ which means all the points within a distance of $ {r}_{i} $ from $ {m}_{ii} $.

Now, for each row the radius is composed of the Cross Correlation between different elements of your variable which can be bounded by $ {a}_{i} {a}_{j} $ which will give you what you need.

Since this is a covariance matrix and all $ {m}_{ii} $ are positive you may even sort all bounds by size using the right bound and then have specific bound per eigen value.